# What is the best way to have Server Side Paging query aggregate sql in Jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi what I trying to achieve is to to get returned result of Page the result get in into DTO and request as Pageable. How do I do this properly?

I found couple way but I am not sure and not comfy about it. I every try QueryDsl way, but it have "count" limitation when using aggregate function like sum() with group By with multiple column right now will write nativeQuery with @Query() annotation in my repository, which is will be looked like this:

```
    @Query(name = "find_stock_total", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<StockTotalResponseDto> findStockTotalRsMap(Pageable pageable);
```

Then in my entity class, I have to write @NamedNativeQueries and mapped it with @SqlResultSetMappings, here is how I write it:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "find_stock_total",
                query = "SELECT product_id, product_code, sum(qty) FROM "book_stock"
    where warehouse_code = 'GBKTJKT1' and product_code in('MCM-508','TL-101') and branch_code = 'JKT' and branch_id = '1'
    GROUP BY product_id, product_code",
                resultSetMapping = "stock_total_response_dto"
        ),
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "find_stock_total.count",
                query = "select count(*) from (
    SELECT product_id, product_code, sum(qty) FROM "book_stock"
    where warehouse_code = 'GBKTJKT1' and product_code in('MCM-508','TL-101') and branch_code = 'JKT' and branch_id = '1'
    GROUP BY product_id, product_code
) as count"
        )
})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
        @SqlResultSetMapping(
                name = "stock_total_response_dto",
                classes = @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = StockTotalResponseDto.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "product_id", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "product_code", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "sum", type = BigInteger.class)
                        }
                )
        ),
        @SqlResultSetMapping(
                name = "stock_total_response_dto.count",
                columns = @ColumnResult(name = "count")
        )
})
@Entity
```

I will have to write sql string in a @Entity class and I can't use Sort that provided by Pageable and I have to write extra Count query. I want to use Pageable Sort, to sort my data. is there another way to write something like that in better way or maybe modern way? Maybe someone can provide "Criteria" way or there is another Jpa way? Or something better than this?

Comment: You could ditch the DTO, define a database view and map an entity to that. You can than then use the QueryDsl sort, page, filter without any issues.

Comment: If i do that the page size will mess up right? Because i have to sum and group by inside java code level, not sql code level

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout what [Blaze-Persistence](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/#pagination) has to offer which works on top of JPA/Hibernate and also has an integration with spring-data-jpa which allows you to use it as a drop-in replacement for what spring-data-jpa does normally.

It supports aggregation functions properly (also for count queries), has support for keyset pagination and much more. Checkout the documentation about the Spring Data integration: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-integration